# FWrite issue on shared hosting

Tags: php, fwrite, shared-hosting

I'm using a class provided by xPaw, his [Source Query Lib](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query) and it works perfectly fine on my local environment. However I uploaded it to my shared hosting and now get this error:

```
ErrorException in SourceRcon.class.php line 75:
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

I have no idea why this is happening on just the shared host as it works perfectly fine locally.

Any ideas as to why it might be happening?

Direct link to the file: https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query/blob/master/SourceQuery/SourceRcon.class.php

Thanks, -Nick

Comment: paste relivent code here, not some where else

Comment: @Dagon it's quite a long file but I suppose I can...

Comment: `$this->RconSocket` is a boolean, work out why

Comment: @Dagon i've looked into why, found no answer. Why is it working fine locally but not on shared hosting is the issue. It shouldn't change.

Comment: you can sit there and say it works on x but not y or you can start debugging based on the very helpful error messages